# Spring batch JPAItemReader performance Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

Below is the configuration of my spring batch job which takes records from DB, do some processing in item processor, updates status column and writes back to DB.

When I ran for 10k records, I could see its taking every record one by one and updating status in the same manner. Initially I was planning to use multithreading but it doesn't make any sense as my job runs once in a day with number of records ranging from 10 to 100k. ( Records are less than 5k in most of the days and a very few days in a year ( 5 to 10 days) it comes to 50k to 100k).

I don't want to add more cpus and getting charged by Kubernetes just for 10 days of an year. Now the problem is when I ran this job, it takes only 100 records that it runs every select query independently instead of taking 100 at a time. Also update is also one record at a time and it takes 10 mins to process 10k records which is really slow.

**How can do a faster read, process and write?** I can get rid of multithreading and have a bit more of CPU utilization once in a while. More information is given as comments in code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

public final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
MyRepository myRepository;


@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Value("${chunk-size}")
private int chunkSize;

@Value("${max-threads}")
private int maxThreads;

private final DataSource dataSource;


/**
 * @param dataSource
 * Override to do not set datasource even if a datasource exist during intialization.
 * Initialize will use a Map based JobRepository (instead of database) for Spring batch meta tables
 */
@Override
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
}

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return jpaTransactionManager();
}


@Autowired
public BatchConfiguration(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return transactionManager;
}


@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcPagingItemReader<ModelEntity> importReader() {  // I tried using RepositoryItemReader but records were skipped by JPA hence I went for JdbcPagingItemReader
    JdbcPagingItemReader<ModelEntity> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<ModelEntity>();
    final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource( dataSource );
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause( "SELECT *" );
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause( "FROM mytable" );
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause( "WHERE STATUS = 'myvalue' " );
    sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSortKey( "primarykey" );
    try {
        reader.setQueryProvider( sqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.getObject() );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    reader.setDataSource( dataSource );
    reader.setPageSize( chunkSize );
    reader.setSaveState( Boolean.FALSE );
    reader.setRowMapper( new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ModelEntity>(ModelEntity.class ) );
    return reader;
}



@Bean
public ItemWriter<ModelEntity> databaseWriter() {
    RepositoryItemWriter<ModelEntity> repositoryItemWriter=new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    repositoryItemWriter.setRepository(myRepository);
    repositoryItemWriter.setMethodName("save");
    return repositoryItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public Myprocessor myprocessor() { 
    return new Myprocessor();
}

@Bean
public JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener() {
    return new JobExecutionListener();
}

@Bean
public StepExecutionListener stepExecutionListener() {
    return new StepExecutionListener();
}

@Bean
public ChunkExecutionListener chunkListener() {
    return new ChunkExecutionListener();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
 SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
 taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(maxThreads);
return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Job processJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myjob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(processStep())
            .listener(jobExecutionListener())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step processStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processStep")
            .<ModelEntity,ModelEntity>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(importReader())
            .processor(myprocessor())
            .writer(databaseWriter())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .listener(stepExecutionListener())
            .listener(chunkListener())
            .transactionManager(getTransactionManager())
            .throttleLimit(maxThreads)
            .build();
    }

}
```

Repository that I am using is `JpaRepository` and code below. (Assuming save method of its parent class CrudRepository will do save)

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<ModelEntity, BigInteger> {

}
```

**Processor is as below**

```
@Component
public class Myprocessor implements ItemProcessor<Myprocessor,Myprocessor> {

@Override
public ModelEntity process(ModelEntity modelEntity) throws Exception {
    try {
    // This is fast and working fine
       if ((myProcessing)) {
            modelEntity.setStatus(success);
        } else {
            modelEntity.setStatus(failed);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        logger.info( "Exception occurred while processing"+e );
      }
    return modelEntity;
 }

 // This is fast and working fine
 public Boolean myProcessing(ModelEntity modelEntity){
 //Processor Logic Here
    return processingStatus;
 }

 }
```

**Properties file below**

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE 
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE


spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password 
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class
=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
spring.batch.initialize-schema=never 
chunk-size=100
max-threads=5
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the method `saveAll` instead of `save` in your `repositoryItemWriter`?

Comment: Yes I tried the same also. But that was not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I found the issue myself. I was using JdbcPagingItemReader and RepositoryItemWriter. The reader was working as expected, but the writer was triggering a select query for each record passed after processor. I believe reason behind is that the the record is persistent to JPA only after processor since the reader is not a standard JPA reader. I am not sure about it though. But changing the writer to JdbcBatchItemWriter fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable JDBC batch processing for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements with just one configuration property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size
```

It determines the number of updates that are sent to the database at one time for execution.

For details, see [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch)